# With Apache Poi how do I create multivalue spreadsheet cells so displayed properly in MS Excel not just OpenOffice

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, openoffice.org

I am using Jakarta Poi to create an .xlsx file from Java which can be opened in Excel/Office. Some of the cells represent multiple values and are originally null separated e.g 'fred/u000/tom' when I set in the cell I replace the null characters with '\n'

This all worked fine with OpenOffice, it raises the height of these rows to accomodate the multiple lines. But I found OpenOffice was taking a significantly longer to open files in xlsx format then xls format so I invested in Microsoft Excel and this displays the same file with all the values all on a single line.

[image: Open Office]

[image: MS Excel]

If you go into edit a value then Excel increases the height to accomodate the multiple values, but why doesn't it do it on read.

[image: MS Excel Edit]
Since there is no need to edit the spreadsheet is there something else I can use instead of '\n' or some option to force Excel to display the file like OpenOffice

code extract

```
private void addFieldValue(Session session, Worksheet sheet, Row r, int spreadsheetIndex, SongFieldNameColumnWidth sfncw, SongChanges fieldChanges, Song song)
{
    SongFieldName   songFieldName = sfncw.getSongFieldName();
    String          value = "";
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell c ;
    c=r.createCell(spreadsheetIndex);

    //Chnanges have been made to this field
    if(fieldChanges!=null)
    {
        if (changeType == SongChangeType.ADD)
        {
            value = fieldChanges.getNewValue().replace('\u0000', '\n');
            c.setCellValue(value);
            c.setCellStyle(fieldAddedStyle);

        }
        else if (changeType == SongChangeType.EDIT)
        {
            value = fieldChanges.getNewValue().replace('\u0000', '\n');
            c.setCellValue(value);
            c.setCellStyle(fieldChangedStyle);
            //addCellComment(r, c, sheet, fieldChanges.getOriginalValue());
        }
        else if (changeType == SongChangeType.DELETE)
        {
            c.setCellStyle(fieldDeletedStyle);
        }
    }
    sfncw.setColumnWidthFromValue(value);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your generation code, we haven't a lot of hope of being able to see your mistake...

Comment: @Gagravarr i have now added some code, but really I already explained how i was setting the data in the question.

Comment: If you enter the value you want to see in Excel, then read that back from Apache POI, how does POI see the cell value as having been done? Maybe `\r` or `\r\n` ?

Comment: @Gagravaar I tried changing my code to write \r\n. now Excel still displays as one line but when double click it display with an empty line between each record, not what wanted. I think the data is correct, the issue is that Excel does not adjust its display by default to properly show on multiple lines.

Comment: I cannot see any difference between using '\n' and '\r'

Comment: Seems as if the `fieldAddedStyle`, `fieldChangedStyle` and `fieldDeletedStyle` are [CellStyles](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html). So make sure that [setWrapText](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setWrapText(boolean)) is set `true` at least for `fieldAddedStyle` and `fieldChangedStyle`.

Comment: @AxelRichter when i saw your comment I thought you had solved it but it has made no difference, in fact if I set it to false it OpenOffice still displays okay so seems to have no effect :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not clear from your code what you are doing wrong, but as said in my comment,  [setWrapText](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setWrapText(boolean))  needs to be set true in the [CellStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html) for cells which shall have line wraps.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class CreateExcelCellWrapText {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

  CellStyle cellstyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellstyle.setWrapText(true);

  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("String cell content\nhaving line wrap.");
  cell.setCellStyle(cellstyle);

  sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelCellWrapText.xlsx"));
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Does your example work if you remove sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);

Comment: Ah, sorry silly mistake on my part, the code does not show unchanged fields and unchanged fields did not have a cellstyle and when I ran my test all the fields were unchanged, hence your fix was not being applied. I can confirm it now works, thankyou.